# Launch an existing Android App from a web link

Tags: android

I'm considering developing a web-based resource for our sales reps to use on their tablets.  Among other information, I'd like to include links that would launch other applications on the tablet.  For example, a link to the Google Drive app, (maybe even to a specific folder).  Or maybe a link to the Android Gallery.  Is this possible?

Comment: what have you tested and how?

Comment: So far I have created the following test page:  http://67.199.95.69/mobile/default.asp#

Comment: My intention is to simply save this as a shortcut on the sales teams tablets, set to launch in either Dolphin or Chrome.  When the user clicks on the PDF link, for example, I would like to launch the Drive App rather than just accessing Drive via the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, you have to use an intent filter and a custom scheme for the url.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2958870/1552551

Comment: I saw this, but perhaps there's something I'm missing.  Adding an <intent-filter> has to be done in the AndroidManifest.xml file of the app, correct?  So if I am accessing this mobile resource through the Chrome browser on my tablet, does that mean I need to access Chrome's AndroidManifest.xml file and add the <intent-filter> there?